# how to call soap wcf webservices using ws.js or wcf.js node modules?

Tags: node.js, soap, module, wsdl, npm

I have installed soapjs module and tried to access those service.

This service contains complexContent:
http://www.reportingsales.com/DeFactoSF1.asmx?WSDL

Could we get wcf service wsdl details(methods, input, output) using soapjs?
http://mli.crmnext.com/CRMnextWebApi/CRMnextService.svc?wsdl

Kindly give me some suggestions..

if possible give me some working soap client examples of those modules

Answer (score 0):

ws.js and wcf.js are about defining security/mtom. they do not deal with the xml format, you need to bring the xml out of band (maybe copy a working sample from your logs).